# How can I do this iPhone (segmentedcontrol?) layout?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

Please look at this screenshot:
[image]

When you tap in another segmentedcontrol, it switches smoothly (try it if you can).

First of all, is it a segmentedcontrol?
Second, how can I add this smooth effect?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't really understand how we're supposed to try it from a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried. It does not seem to be a segment view. 
Maybe 3 dark buttons(or view or views) and a layer that moves and overlay the current selected button.
Everything is well crafted so it looks great ;)

I think I could do that with a big UIImageView (instead of the three buttons) with an UITapGestureRecognizer to get the touch and a CALayer for the selected *button*

Comment: Ok, a big UIImageView with three buttons. But for the "smooth switch" effect? How it works in your opinion?

Comment: easy as layer.position=CGMakePoint(x,y); since layer is a CALayer object is making simple animations with it is super easy. I thought of CALayers not only because animations does not have to be explicit but also because CALayers don't receive touches and are lighter. Something that fits perfect to this case